# Constant 400 response, sending complex javascript object to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Yet again another MVC issue. One day I'll look at my "MVC learning days" and smile.

So to the point and exactly as the title indicates; A constant 400 response, I've read numerous posts on SO and still cannot seem to get my logic working. If I may show you the logic, someone maybe able to help me.

Controller:

```
public JsonResult CreateExtendedProperty(ExtendedPropertyDefinitionViewModel extendedPropertyDefinitionViewModel)
{

   //I originally had JsonResult as ActionResult, still no change.
    var p = extendedPropertyDefinitionViewModel;

    //Temp
    //return Json(new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = "Error creating property" });
}
```

The Ajax/Javascript:

```
        var extendedPropertyDefinition = JSON.stringify({
            DefinitionId: '0',
            Title: propertyInfo["Title"],
            OrganisationId: '0',
            Organisation: '',
            TypeId: propertyInfo["TypeId"],
            SortOrder: 0,
            IsEnumerated: propertyInfo["IsEnumerated"],
            AllowMultiSelect: propertyInfo["AllowMultiSelect"],
            IsDate: propertyInfo["IsDate"],
            LastUpdatedBy: "",
            LastUpdatedDateTime: new Date().toISOString(),
            CreatedBy: "",
            CreatedByDateTime: new Date().toISOString(),
            Options: {
                OptionId: '0',
                Option: '',
                OptionValue: '',
                SortOrder: 0,
                LastUpdatedBy: '',
                LastUpdatedDateTime: new Date().toISOString(),
                CreatedBy: '',
                CreatedByDateTime: new Date().toISOString(),
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "<%= Url.Action('CreateExtendedProperty', 'Organisation') %>",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            //traditional: true,
            type: 'POST',
            data: extendedPropertyDefinition,
            success: function(e) {
                alert('success');
                //Rebuild Grid? 
            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert('request failed (500)');

            }
        });
```

The payload:
[image]

Hopefully someone can put on the right path, all will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Your question is too vague, I don't know how to answer you.  Your controller method does nothing as far as I can tell so I'm not sure how it could be generating a 400 response.

Comment: To be honest it's far from vague; more illustrative then anything. Exactly it is bare, so thoughts are, its not actually hitting.

Comment: try remove `JSON.stringify` and pass `data: {extendedPropertyDefinitionViewModel: extendedPropertyDefinition},`

Comment: @Grundy Just tried that, still doesn't work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: ok, can you provide full error that you get? i mean not only _status_

Comment: It literally is this: <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p> Iv'e ran the debugger, debugged the js. Still nothing.

Comment: can you add screenshot this error in your browser console?

Comment: @TezWingfield Does `<%= Url.Action('CreateExtendedProperty', 'Organisation') %>` get compiled? Is your JS code embedded into CSHTML?

Comment: @Kamo Well it appears that it doesn't, So I assume that would be the issue. Teaching myself MVC is destroying my brain haha

Comment: Have you tried just writing the url in the js? '/Organisation/CreateExtendedProperty'  This is assuming your controller name is Organisation since we can't see the full controller code

Comment: If your script is in a separate _js_ file then `<%= Url.Action('CreateExtendedProperty', 'Organisation') %>` will not get rendered by the view engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to just get the answer from comments - you have to ensure that `<%= Url.Action('CreateExtendedProperty', 'Organisation') %>` gets compiled. If it is in a separate JS file you have to pass it from your view. Otherwise it could be some other problem(if you are using Razor syntax, it should something like `@Url.Action("CreateExtendedProperty", "Organisation")`)